# Browser ignores z-index on overlay div

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my page I have a navigation bar with a button that toggles a full-screen overlay. The button changes from three bars to a cross so it always needs to stay on top of the navigation so that it can be accessed by the user to close the overlay once they are finished with it. Here is the code that does this:

```js
document.getElementById("navigation-toggle").onclick = function() {
  "use strict";
  document.getElementById("navigation-toggle").classList.toggle("navigation-toggle-animation");
  document.getElementById("navigation").classList.toggle("navigation-show");
};
```

```css
#brandbar {
  background: #007cff;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#brandbar-product {
  float: left;
}

#brandbar-product-icon {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#brandbar-product-text {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
}

#brandbar-product-text a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation {
  background-color: #000000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  color: #ffffff;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navigation-hide {
  height: 0%;
}

.navigation-show {
  height: 100%;
}

#navigation-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 7.5px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#navigation-toggle-bar-1,
#navigation-toggle-bar-2,
#navigation-toggle-bar-3 {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 25px;
}

#navigation-toggle-bar-1,
#navigation-toggle-bar-2 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.navigation-toggle-animation #navigation-toggle-bar-1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 9px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 9px);
}

.navigation-toggle-animation #navigation-toggle-bar-2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navigation-toggle-animation #navigation-toggle-bar-3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -9px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -9px);
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Reset Styles*/

body {
  background-color: #f3f3ee;
  color: #24292e;
  font-family: Roboto;
  padding-top: 120px !important;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="brandbar">
  <div id="brandbar-product">

    <a href="https://www.digytool.com/" title="Go to Digytool"><img alt="The Digytool Icon" id="brandbar-product-icon" src="https://system.digytool.com/images/icon/digytool-white.png" title="Digytool Icon"></a>

    <h1 id="brandbar-product-text"><a href="https://www.digytool.com/" title="Go to Digytool">Digytool</a></h1>

  </div>

  <div id="navigation-toggle">
    <div id="navigation-toggle-bar-1"></div>
    <div id="navigation-toggle-bar-2"></div>
    <div id="navigation-toggle-bar-3"></div>
  </div>


</div>

<div class="navigation-hide" id="navigation">
  Navigation<br> Navigation
  <br> Navigation
  <br> Navigation
  <br> Navigation
  <br> Navigation
  <br>
</div>
```

My problem is that the button is not keeping on top of the overlay, even though the button has `z-index: 2` and the overlay has `z-index: 1`. I have tested it out in Chrome, IE / Edge and Safari and these browsers all seem to have the issue.

Just to explain...

- `#brandbar` is the main navigation bar.
- `#brandbar-product` and similar ids are to do with the logo and icon.
- `#navigation` is the overlay.
- `.navigation-hide` and `.navigation-show` toggle the navigation visibility. `.navigation hide` is always assigned to `#navigation` and when `.navigation-show` is added, it overrides `.navigation hide`.
- `#navigation-toggle` and similar ids and classes are to do with the button that toggles the overlay, and the animation that transforms it into a cross.

Could you please explain why the button is not rising to the top of the page, and give an example on how I could fix it.

Comment: The reason you are experiencing this behaviour (something both current answers have failed to address) is because z-index only works between sibling elements. By moving ``navigation-toggle`` up a level it becomes a sibling of ``navigation`` and zindex kicks in correctly

Comment: @cfreear please put that into an answer **with an example** and I will accept it as the solution

Comment: Done, it's largely the same as Rohit Bajaniya's answer but I've provided an explanation of the reason for the behaviour and the changes.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct @cfreear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your close button is staying behind the overlay is because zindex only works between siblings (elements that are next to each other in the page) and not children/ancestors.

In your html `navigation` is a sibling of `brandbar` but `navigation-toggle` is a child of `brandbar` so therefore not a sibling of `navigation`.

Start by moving your `<div id="navigation-toggle">` element up to the same level as `<div class="navigation-hide" id="navigation">`, then change the css for `#navigation-toggle` to add:

```css
position: fixed;
top: 22px;
right: 20px;
```

you can also remove:

```css
float: right;
height: 25px;
```

as they aren't needed.

Here's your code modified:

```js
document.getElementById("navigation-toggle").onclick = function() {
  "use strict";
  document.getElementById("navigation-toggle").classList.toggle("navigation-toggle-animation");
  document.getElementById("navigation").classList.toggle("navigation-show");
};
```

```css
#brandbar {
  background: #007cff;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#brandbar-product {
  float: left;
}

#brandbar-product-icon {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#brandbar-product-text {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
}

#brandbar-product-text a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation {
  background-color: #000000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  color: #ffffff;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navigation-hide {
  height: 0%;
}

.navigation-show {
  height: 100%;
}

#navigation-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 7.5px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  top: 22px;
  right: 20px;
}

#navigation-toggle-bar-1,
#navigation-toggle-bar-2,
#navigation-toggle-bar-3 {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 25px;
}

#navigation-toggle-bar-1,
#navigation-toggle-bar-2 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.navigation-toggle-animation #navigation-toggle-bar-1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 9px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 9px);
}

.navigation-toggle-animation #navigation-toggle-bar-2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navigation-toggle-animation #navigation-toggle-bar-3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -9px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -9px);
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Reset Styles*/

body {
  background-color: #f3f3ee;
  color: #24292e;
  font-family: Roboto;
  padding-top: 120px !important;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation-toggle">
  <div id="navigation-toggle-bar-1"></div>
  <div id="navigation-toggle-bar-2"></div>
  <div id="navigation-toggle-bar-3"></div>
</div>

<div id="brandbar">
  <div id="brandbar-product">
    <a href="https://www.digytool.com/" title="Go to Digytool"><img alt="The Digytool Icon" id="brandbar-product-icon" src="https://system.digytool.com/images/icon/digytool-white.png" title="Digytool Icon"></a>
    <h1 id="brandbar-product-text"><a href="https://www.digytool.com/" title="Go to Digytool">Digytool</a></h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="navigation-hide" id="navigation">
  Navigation
  <br> Navigation
  <br> Navigation
  <br> Navigation
  <br> Navigation
  <br> Navigation
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementById("navigation-toggle").onclick = function() {
  "use strict";
  document.getElementById("navigation-toggle").classList.toggle("navigation-toggle-animation");
  document.getElementById("navigation").classList.toggle("navigation-show");
};
```

```css
#brandbar {
  background: #007cff;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#brandbar-product {
  float: left;
}

#brandbar-product-icon {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#brandbar-product-text {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
}

#brandbar-product-text a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation {
  background-color: #000000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  color: #ffffff;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navigation-hide {
  height: 0%;
}

.navigation-show {
  height: 100%;
}

#navigation-toggle {
cursor: pointer;
float: right;
height: 25px;
margin: 7.5px;
z-index: 2;
position: fixed;
top: 22px;
right: 20px;
}

#navigation-toggle-bar-1,
#navigation-toggle-bar-2,
#navigation-toggle-bar-3 {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 25px;
}

#navigation-toggle-bar-1,
#navigation-toggle-bar-2 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.navigation-toggle-animation #navigation-toggle-bar-1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 9px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 9px);
}

.navigation-toggle-animation #navigation-toggle-bar-2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navigation-toggle-animation #navigation-toggle-bar-3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -9px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -9px);
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Reset Styles*/

body {
  background-color: #f3f3ee;
  color: #24292e;
  font-family: Roboto;
  padding-top: 120px !important;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <div id="navigation-toggle">
    <div id="navigation-toggle-bar-1"></div>
    <div id="navigation-toggle-bar-2"></div>
    <div id="navigation-toggle-bar-3"></div>
  </div>

<div id="brandbar">
  <div id="brandbar-product">

    <a href="https://www.digytool.com/" title="Go to Digytool"><img alt="The Digytool Icon" id="brandbar-product-icon" src="https://system.digytool.com/images/icon/digytool-white.png" title="Digytool Icon"></a>

    <h1 id="brandbar-product-text"><a href="https://www.digytool.com/" title="Go to Digytool">Digytool</a></h1>

  </div>


</div>

<div class="navigation-hide" id="navigation">
  Navigation<br> Navigation
  <br> Navigation
  <br> Navigation
  <br> Navigation
  <br> Navigation
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: I have changed "#navigation-toggle" css class and "navigation-toggle" link append in body tag.

Comment: It's best to provide a description of your solution in your answer instead of just providing code, stack overflow is a learning site.

Comment: @cfreear yes, please edit your answer with a description of what you did.